# iPad + Jquery scrolling works right once, and then stops

Tags: jquery, ipad, scroll

I can't test my website because I don't have an iPad, but the guy I'm working for went to an apple store yesterday to try it out and had strange behavior.

So it's a horizontal scrolling website, and if you click on the navigation it uses jquery to scroll to the element referring to the link. This works fine in all browsers, with no console errors in firefox, chrome, or IE9.

Problem on the iPad though, is that clicking a link the first time works fine - it scrolls just as it should. But after that, clicking links no longer works. He said it would move just a few pixels then stop.

I signed a non-disclosure agreement so I can't show the website, but here is the code I tied to navigation. Is there anything wrong here? Has anyone experienced this sort of problem on the iPad?

```
$("#navhome, #logo").bind('click', function(event) {
    // Home button and the page logo send you to the #home element
    event.preventDefault();
    scrollToID($("#home"), this);
});

function scrollToID(id, nav) {
    $("html, body").stop();
    xtarget = id.position().left;
    $("html, body").animate({scrollLeft: xtarget}, 'slow');
}
```

I mean, this seems like the way to do it. Why would the ipad give any trouble?

I'll keep browsing google for now, I don't expect much without being able to link the page. :/

Comment: If you are using Xcode to package your app then you can use the simulator in iPad mode.

Comment: Not constructive, but: There's no need to provide a context for an ID selector. `$("#navhome, #logo")` can be shortened to `$("#navhome")`

Comment: No xcode, I wish I could use the ipad and iphone simulators though.

And for the ID selectors, there's a comma there. I'm selecting both #navhome and #logo as buttons individually. They both go to the same place, but they are separate buttons.

Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming back to this issue, after receiving an email from someone with a similar issue.

The problem I had was that I made the entire website stretch the body of the page, which worked fine with iPad's touch-controls (like swiping). However, by doing this I needed to move the navigation box either with javascript (jagged) or position: fixed (smooth, but poor mobile support).

Then a bug in iOS5 arose, I'm still not sure on the cause but it's related to scrolling via jQuery animation and using a moving div with clickable elements during movement.

The navigation would become unclickable until the animation stops, but sometimes it would become unclickable even after the animation, until you interacted with the website by scrolling, zooming, etc. Obviously, this workaround is not user-friendly.

My final solution was to instead wrap the contents in a div that is sized to the width of the browser. As you might know, iPad and similar touch devices do not have native touch support for scrolling a div, just limited scrolling.

There is probably a better solution out there somewhere, but for now, we're just wrapping it in a div so that our navigation doesn't have to move at all. Only our content moves, contained within itself.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post more code? Your example seems to work fine for me on my iPad.

http://jsfiddle.net/DzyYT/

http://jsfiddle.net/DzyYT/show (for iPad users)

I noticed one bug. When using a swipe to scroll sideways it moves with momentum. If the screen is still sliding when you click the return to home button it does not work.

Comment: I appreciate the testing, it's good to hear that the function works at least. I found an inconsistency in this script, although I'm not sure if its a bug. All of my other navigation scripts use .stop(true, false) so that it clears the animation queue. The ipad's just uses .stop(). Because I wasn't the one to test the ipad, I'm not sure if it barely moving was because it had queued up wrong Maybe he double clicked on the first link, or maybe a touch event counted twice. I don't know, I'll have to try it again before trying to fix it.

Comment: I added my current solution to this question, thought I should update your answer with a comment. The reason your testing did not have the issue I described is that it is due to a bug in iOS5. You probably had used a first generation ipad, or something similar with an older iOS version.